# Trouble installing nlme package

Tags: r, macos, nlme

I need to install nlme as it is a dependency for the MSstats package I need. I currently run on R version 4.2.0. When I try to install with Bioc manager I get the following:

```
> BiocManager::install("MSstats")
'getOption("repos")' replaces Bioconductor standard repositories, see '?repositories' for details

replacement repositories:
    CRAN: https://cran.rstudio.com/

Bioconductor version 3.15 (BiocManager 1.30.18), R 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Old packages: 'nlme'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: 
a

  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary  source needs_compilation
nlme 3.1-157 3.1-158              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘nlme’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/nlme_3.1-158.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 845427 bytes (825 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 825 KB

* installing *source* package ‘nlme’ ...
** package ‘nlme’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c chol.f -o chol.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c corStruct.c -o corStruct.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c gnls.c -o gnls.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c init.c -o init.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c matrix.c -o matrix.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlOptimizer.c -o nlOptimizer.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlme.c -o nlme.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c nlmefit.c -o nlmefit.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c pdMat.c -o pdMat.o
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/include   -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c pythag.c -o pythag.o
gfortran -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -Wall -g -O2  -c rs.f -o rs.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o nlme.so chol.o corStruct.o gnls.o init.o matrix.o nlOptimizer.o nlme.o nlmefit.o pdMat.o pythag.o rs.o -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [nlme.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nlme’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/nlme’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/nlme’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/qx/5klvf6g112zb1vzzp5bt8n9r0000gn/T/Rtmpz9mEK5/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: package(s) not installed when version(s) same as current; use `force = TRUE` to re-install: 'MSstats' 
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
  installation of package ‘nlme’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: `gcc` installed? See [there](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8336714)

Comment: @jay.sf gcc is already installed